POSTGIS - Query not using index
Im new to postgres, sql and all RDBMS in general so am working on a project to further my knowledge. Im building a room finding website. Each room is part of a property and each property can have multiple rooms. I want to do a proximity search and am using postgis.
property table (other irrelevant columns removed):



id
title
geoLocation




SERIAL PK
TEXT
GEOGRAPHY(Point)



room table (other irrelevant columns removed):



id
propertyId
rent
available
geoLocation




SERIAL PK
INTEGER REFERENCES property(id)
INTEGER
BOOLEAN
GEOGRAPHY(Point)



I have a query where i try to find the closest properties within a given radius $3 to a given point (lng $1, lat $2) and where at least one room is within 50 dollars and 10,000 dollars and is available. I then return then each property once with all rooms part of it that matched as an element in rooms
I created an index on the geolocation on the property table: 
property_geolocation_idx_geography" gist (geolocation)
I also have an index on the room table: 
room_geolocation_idx" gist (geolocation)
I have a dataset of ~70,000 properties and ~150,000 rooms. When i run the query below not only is it incredibly slow at 13 seconds, but it also doesn't use the index I've created. Running an explain on the query below shows:
 Limit  (cost=429967.49..429969.26 rows=1 width=1192)
   ->  Result  (cost=429953.31..429967.49 rows=8 width=1192)
         ->  Sort  (cost=429953.31..429953.33 rows=8 width=1176)
               Sort Key: ((property.geolocation <-> '0101000020E61000000432E0D16B58ACBF84ABF2F395C54940'::geography))
               ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=429945.11..429953.19 rows=8 width=1176)
                     Group Key: property.id
                     ->  Gather Merge  (cost=429945.11..429946.03 rows=8 width=1198)
                           Workers Planned: 1
                           ->  Sort  (cost=428945.10..428945.12 rows=5 width=1198)
                                 Sort Key: property.id
                                 ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=425488.95..428945.04 rows=5 width=1198)
                                       Hash Cond: (room.propertyid = property.id)
                                       ->  Parallel Seq Scan on room  (cost=0.00..3335.06 rows=46104 width=66)
                                             Filter: (available AND (rent > 50) AND (rent < 10000))
                                       ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=425488.91..425488.91 rows=3 width=1136)
                                             ->  Parallel Index Scan using property_pkey on property  (cost=0.29..425488.91 rows=3 width=1136)
                                                   Filter: st_dwithin((geolocation)::geography, '0101000020E61000000432E0D16B58ACBF84ABF2F395C54940'::geography, '13118244

So my questions: 
Is this query garbage? 
If so why? 
How could I improve? 
Why is my index not being picked up? 
SELECT
            property.*,
            json_agg(
                json_build_object(
                    'id', room.id,
                    'rent', room.rent,
                    'available', room.available,
                )
            ) AS rooms,
            ST_X(ST_AsText(property.geoLocation::geometry)) AS longitude,
            ST_Y(ST_AsText(property.geoLocation::geometry)) AS latitude
        FROM
            property
    
        LEFT JOIN
            room ON property.id = room.propertyId
        WHERE
            room.available = TRUE
            AND room.rent > 50
            AND room.rent < 10000
            AND ST_DWITHIN(property.geoLocation::geography, ST_MakePoint($1, $2)::geography, $3)
        GROUP BY
            property.id
        ORDER BY
            property.geoLocation <-> ST_MakePoint($1, $2)::geography
        LIMIT 
            ${PROPERTIES_PER_PAGE}
        OFFSET
            ${offset};

@frank - I had to remove some fluff to be within question limit
Limit  (cost=429967.49..429969.26 rows=1 width=1192) (actual time=7531.979..7590.966 rows=12 loops=1)
   Output: property.id, property.title, property.geolocation, (json_agg(json_build_object('id', room.id, 'rent', 'available': room.available, room.rent, 'geoLocation', st_astext(room.geolocation)))), (st_x((st_astext((property.geolocation)::geometry))::geometry)), (st_y((st_astext((property.geolocation)::geometry))::geometry)), ((property.geolocation <-> '0101000020E61000000432E0D16B58ACBF84ABF2F395C54940'::geography))
   Buffers: shared hit=17479, temp read=33222 written=33355
   ->  Result  (cost=429953.31..429967.49 rows=8 width=1192) (actual time=7177.756..7236.970 rows=24 loops=1)
         Output: property.id, property.title, property.geolocation, (json_agg(json_build_object('id', room.id, 'rent', 'available': room.available, room.rent, 'geoLocation', st_astext(room.geolocation)))), st_x((st_astext((property.geolocation)::geometry))::geometry), st_y((st_astext((property.geolocation)::geometry))::geometry), ((property.geolocation <-> '0101000020E61000000432E0D16B58ACBF84ABF2F395C54940'::geography))
         Buffers: shared hit=17479, temp read=33222 written=33355
         ->  Sort  (cost=429953.31..429953.33 rows=8 width=1176) (actual time=7174.578..7233.292 rows=24 loops=1)
               Output: property.id, property.title, property.geolocation, (json_agg(json_build_object('id', room.id, 'rent', 'available': room.available, room.rent, 'geoLocation', st_astext(room.geolocation)))), ((property.geolocation <-> '0101000020E61000000432E0D16B58ACBF84ABF
2F395C54940'::geography))
               Sort Key: ((property.geolocation <-> '0101000020E61000000432E0D16B58ACBF84ABF2F395C54940'::geography))
               Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 105kB
               Buffers: shared hit=17479, temp read=33222 written=33355
               ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=429945.11..429953.19 rows=8 width=1176) (actual time=2423.912..6885.664 rows=53898 loops=1)
                     Output: property.id, property.title, property.geolocation, (json_agg(json_build_object('id', room.id, 'rent', 'available': room.available, room.rent, 'geoLocation', st_astext(room.geolocation)))), ((property.geolocation <-> '0101000020E61000000432E0D16B58ACBF84ABF
2F395C54940'::geography))
                     Group Key: property.id
                     Buffers: shared hit=17476, temp read=33222 written=33355
                     ->  Gather Merge  (cost=429945.11..429946.03 rows=8 width=1198) (actual time=2421.322..2746.490 rows=78896 loops=1)
                           Output: property.id, property.title, property.geolocation, room.id, room.fur
nished, room.minstay, room.maxstay, room.roomtype, room.ensuite, room.deposit, room.rent, room.billsincluded, room.geolocation
                           Workers Planned: 1
                           Workers Launched: 1
                           Buffers: shared hit=17476, temp read=33222 written=33355
                           ->  Sort  (cost=428945.10..428945.12 rows=5 width=1198) (actual time=2229.847..2358.638 rows=39448 loops=2)
                                 Output: property.id, property.title, property.geolocation, room.id, ro
om.furnished, room.minstay, room.maxstay, room.roomtype, room.ensuite, room.deposit, room.rent, room.billsincluded, room.geolocation
                                 Sort Key: property.id
                                 Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 46944kB
                                 Buffers: shared hit=17476, temp read=33222 written=33355
                                 Worker 0:  actual time=2047.542..2175.107 rows=39565 loops=1
                                   Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 47224kB
                                   JIT:
                                     Functions: 14
                                     Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
                                     Timing: Generation 20.206 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 21.590 ms, Emission 222.751 ms, Total 264.547 ms
                                   Buffers: shared hit=7466, temp read=16260 written=16527
                                 ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=425488.95..428945.04 rows=5 width=1198) (actual time=1610.287..1814.868 rows=39448 loops=2)
                                       Output: property.id, property.title, property.geolocation, room.
id, room.furnished, room.minstay, room.maxstay, room.roomtype, room.ensuite, room.deposit, room.rent, room.billsincluded, room.geolocation
                                       Inner Unique: true
                                       Hash Cond: (room.propertyid = property.id)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=17440, temp read=21451 written=21560
                                       Worker 0:  actual time=1427.075..1632.771 rows=39565 loops=1
                                         Buffers: shared hit=7430, temp read=10357 written=10612
                                       ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.room  (cost=0.00..3335.06 rows=46104 width=66) (actual time=0.635..63.550 rows=39448 loops=2)
                                             Output: room.id, room.propertyid, room.furnished, room.minstay, room.maxstay, room.roomtype, room.ensuite, room.deposit, room
rty.dishwasher, property.dryer, property.livingroom, property.parking, property.garage, property.disabledaccess, property.images, property.location, property.geolocation,
 property.closeststation, property.closeststationtype, property.distancetocloseststation, property.dateavailable, property.postauthor, (json_agg(json_build_object('id', r
oom.id, 'furnished', room.furnished, 'minStay', room.minstay, 'maxStay', room.maxstay, 'roomType', room.roomtype, 'ensuite', room.ensuite, 'deposit', room.deposit, 'rent'
, room.rent, 'billsIncluded', room.billsincluded, 'geoLocation', st_astext(room.geolocation)))), st_x((st_astext((property.geolocation)::geometry))::geometry), st_y((st_a
stext((property.geolocation)::geometry))::geometry), ((property.geolocation <-> '0101000020E61000000432E0D16B58ACBF84ABF2F395C54940'::geography))
         Buffers: shared hit=17479, temp read=33222 written=33355
         ->  Sort  (cost=429953.31..429953.33 rows=8 width=1176) (actual time=7174.578..7233.292 rows=24 loops=1)
               Output: property.id, property.title, property.geolocation, (json_agg(json_build_object('
id', room.id, 'furnished', room.furnished, 'minStay', room.minstay, 'maxStay', room.maxstay, 'roomType', room.roomtype, 'ensuite', room.ensuite, 'deposit', room.deposit,
'rent', room.rent, 'billsIncluded', room.billsincluded, 'geoLocation', st_astext(room.geolocation)))), ((property.geolocation <-> '0101000020E61000000432E0D16B58ACBF84ABF
2F395C54940'::geography))
               Sort Key: ((property.geolocation <-> '0101000020E61000000432E0D16B58ACBF84ABF2F395C54940'::geography))
               Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 105kB
               Buffers: shared hit=17479, temp read=33222 written=33355
               ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=429945.11..429953.19 rows=8 width=1176) (actual time=2423.912..6885.664 rows=53898 loops=1)
                     Output: property.id, property.title, property.geolocation, json_agg(json_build_obj
ect('id', room.id, 'furnished', room.furnished, 'minStay', room.minstay, 'maxStay', room.maxstay, 'roomType', room.roomtype, 'ensuite', room.ensuite, 'deposit', room.depo
sit, 'rent', room.rent, 'billsIncluded', room.billsincluded, 'geoLocation', st_astext(room.geolocation))), (property.geolocation <-> '0101000020E61000000432E0D16B58ACBF84
ABF2F395C54940'::geography)
                     Group Key: property.id
                     Buffers: shared hit=17476, temp read=33222 written=33355
                     ->  Gather Merge  (cost=429945.11..429946.03 rows=8 width=1198) (actual time=2421.322..2746.490 rows=78896 loops=1)
                           Output: property.id, property.title, property.geolocation, room.id, room.fur
nished, room.minstay, room.maxstay, room.roomtype, room.ensuite, room.deposit, room.rent, room.billsincluded, room.geolocation
                           Workers Planned: 1
                           Workers Launched: 1
                           Buffers: shared hit=17476, temp read=33222 written=33355
                           ->  Sort  (cost=428945.10..428945.12 rows=5 width=1198) (actual time=2229.847..2358.638 rows=39448 loops=2)
                                 Output: property.id, property.title, property.geolocation, room.id, ro
om.furnished, room.minstay, room.maxstay, room.roomtype, room.ensuite, room.deposit, room.rent, room.billsincluded, room.geolocation
                                 Sort Key: property.id
                                 Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 46944kB
                                 Buffers: shared hit=17476, temp read=33222 written=33355
                                 Worker 0:  actual time=2047.542..2175.107 rows=39565 loops=1
                                   Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 47224kB
                                   JIT:
                                     Functions: 14
                                     Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
                                     Timing: Generation 20.206 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 21.590 ms, Emission 222.751 ms, Total 264.547 ms
                                   Buffers: shared hit=7466, temp read=16260 written=16527
                                 ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=425488.95..428945.04 rows=5 width=1198) (actual time=1610.287..1814.868 rows=39448 loops=2)
                                       Output: property.id, property.title, property.geolocation, room.
id, room.furnished, room.minstay, room.maxstay, room.roomtype, room.ensuite, room.deposit, room.rent, room.billsincluded, room.geolocation
                                       Inner Unique: true
                                       Hash Cond: (room.propertyid = property.id)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=17440, temp read=21451 written=21560
                                       Worker 0:  actual time=1427.075..1632.771 rows=39565 loops=1
                                         Buffers: shared hit=7430, temp read=10357 written=10612
                                       ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.room  (cost=0.00..3335.06 rows=46104 width=66) (actual time=0.635..63.550 rows=39448 loops=2)
                                             Output: room.id, room.propertyid, room.furnished, room.minstay, room.maxstay, room.roomtype, room.ensuite, room.deposit, room
.rent, room.billsincluded, room.geolocation, room.available
                                             Filter: (room.available AND (room.rent > 50) AND (room.rent < 10000))
                                             Rows Removed by Filter: 39322
                                             Buffers: shared hit=1945
                                             Worker 0:  actual time=0.728..64.888 rows=39232 loops=1
                                               Buffers: shared hit=968
                                       ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=425488.91..425488.91 rows=3 width=1136) (actual time=1482.090..1482.146 rows=39528 loops=2)
                                             Output: property.id, property.title, property.geolocation
                                             Buckets: 8192 (originally 1024)  Batches: 16 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 6048kB
                                             Buffers: shared hit=15466, temp read=9869 written=20664
                                             Worker 0:  actual time=1305.974..1306.039 rows=31842 loops=1
                                               Buffers: shared hit=6433, temp read=4921 written=10164
                                             ->  Parallel Index Scan using property_pkey on public.property  (cost=0.29..425488.91 rows=3 width=1136) (actual time=252.815
..738.880 rows=39528 loops=2)
                                                   Output: property.id, property.title, property.geolocation
                                                   Filter: st_dwithin((property.geolocation)::geography, '0101000020E61000000432E0D16B58ACBF84ABF2F395C54940'::geography,
'13118244.20337062'::double precision, true)
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=15466
                                                   Worker 0:  actual time=374.090..785.762 rows=31842 loops=1
                                                     Buffers: shared hit=6433
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=13
 Planning Time: 25.125 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 35
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 51.444 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 66.533 ms, Emission 531.520 ms, Total 649.496 ms
 Execution Time: 7636.726 ms
(66 rows)


Could you please share the result from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this query?

Looking at the last line of your EXPLAIN output, it seems that the search radius is at least 13 million meters. Surely that’s a bit extreme?

@FrankHeikens just edited question

@TurePålsson I load 100,00 with a script of randomly generated lngs and lats. I use a large radius as the properties are scattered all over. Large radius is solely to retrieve all properties and rooms. Would limit this radius when the website is actually in use

I was thinking that when your search radius covers more than half the planet, the query optimizer might think that using the index is not worth the trouble.

@TurePålsson  You're absolutely right dude! I edited the script to generate lat/lngs around a given center in a given radius. So about 100,000 in a 10km radius. Ran the query again and hash was used! Good to know, thanks!!
Query now takes 1s. (Will be playing around with geohashing to improve this in the future). Thanks again!
